# Creating a method that validates an ID-number according to certain specifics

Tags: java, swing, methods

I am developing a bank application. It's a school assignment (Java system development), it's my first year, I am still a novice. The purpose with the method I need help with is to validate a ID-number according different specifics.

I have used a part of this [code](http://paulonova.weebly.com/personnumer-validering/personnummer-validering-java-programming), but modified it.  Now when I have written the ID-number into the text-frame nothing happens. I am using card-layout. This method is located on the "register" panel. The idea is that the should be able to login at the next panel if the ID-number (and the password) is correct.

The code I is developed for a console, but I am trying to get it to work with a jFrame. I think this is quite a common school assignment here in Sweden and I don't think it's far-fetched to say that more pupils may have use of the help I may receive here.

```
public class BankFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public BankFrame() {       
        initComponents();    
    }   //This is the  method that I have problems with:

    private void registerBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Register customer = new Register(password);
if (password.equals("")){
        outReg.setText("Enter a password as required.");  
     }
}
void CorrectId() {

        //panel
    }

    public void CorrectId(String id) {
        if (validateNumbers(id)) {
            RegPanel.setVisible(false);          // I am using CardLayout. This method is in the RegPanel. 
            LoginPanel.setVisible(true);         //This shoul allow the user to change to the Login panel if the id is valideted by the method.
            base.removeAll();
            base.add(LoginPanel);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        } else {
            outReg.setText("Enter a valid ID-number before proceeding");
            while (true) {
                id = (regIdIn.getText());
                id = id.replaceAll("-", "").trim();      // A swedish ID number looks like this 890123-0000. I have to remove - to be able to run the method validateNumbers.

                if (id.equals("")) {                     // A warning that should be written on the outReg label.
                    outReg.setText("Enter your id as required.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean validateNumbers(String nm) {  //new String so that "id" keeps it's values.

        int numberSize = nm.length();
        if (numberSize != 10) {  // Warning if the ID-number has too little or too many numbers.
            outReg.setText("Only 10 numbers is allowed!");
            return false;
        } else if (nm.matches("\\d+")) {
            return true;
        } else {                        //Warning if there is letters in the ID-number.
            outReg.setText("You are kidding... I hope! ");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Comment: you have not called correctId() anywhere which i think should be called in registerBtnActionPerformed

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the code as you suggested. A part of the problem solved, but the program is till not working as indented.

Comment: you still haven't called correctId anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. Thank you for your help! I am posting the solution here:

```
   Login newUser = new Login(savedId,password);

 password = (regPasswordIn.getText());


     if (password.equals("")){
    outReg.setText("Enter a password as required."); 

 }else{
        CorrectId();  
     }
```

}

```
public void CorrectId() {
    id = (regIdIn.getText()); //Ta in id
    id = id.replaceAll("-","").trim();
    if (id.equals("")){
        outReg.setText("Enter your id as required.");           
    }else{
     if (validateNumbers(id)){

    RegPanel.setVisible(false);          
    LoginPanel.setVisible(true);
    base.removeAll();
    base.add(LoginPanel);
    revalidate();
    repaint();

    savedId=id;




     }else{
         outReg.setText("Enter a valid ID-number before proceeding");  //Varningstext som även kommer upp 

     }
    }
}

public boolean validateNumbers(String nm) {  //ny String nm för att inte köra över id.
    System.out.println("Hej"+nm.length());//debugg
    boolean returnvar;


    numberSize = nm.length();
    if (numberSize != 10) {  // Felmeddelande ifall att fel antal siffror är ifyllda.
        outReg.setText("Only 10 numbers is allowed!");
       returnvar= false;            
    } else {                       
        returnvar= true;
    }
    return returnvar;
}                                           


private void infoBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:


   //Genom desssa olika Randomgeneratorer tar jag fram ett unikt kontnummer.

   //Clearingnummer :
while (true){
    Random clearingNum = new Random ();
    int clrRange = 8999-7000;  //Formel för swedbanks clearing nummer
    int clr = clearingNum.nextInt(clrRange) + 70000;

// Sista siffran i clearingnumret    
   Random clrDiget = new Random();
    int clrDrange = 9 - 1;
    int clrD = clrDiget.nextInt(clrDrange)+1;

 //Siffrona i själva kontonumret       
    Random actNum = new Random();
    int actRange = 999999999-100000000; //Formel för swedbaks kontonummer
    int act = actNum.nextInt(actRange) + 100000000;

 //Sista siffran i kontonumret    
    Random actDiget = new Random();
    int actDrange = 9 - 1 + 1;
    int actD = actDiget.nextInt(actDrange) + 1;

    String a = ""+clr;  //Konverterar int från randomgeneratorerna till String.
    String b = ""+clrD;
    String c = ""+act;
    String d = ""+actD;

    String accountNumber = a + "-" +b + "," +c +"-" +d; //Sätter ihop kontonumrets olika delar i korrektformat.
    accountNumberOut.setText(accountNumber); //Skriver ut kontinummret.
    break;
}




    Customer accountNumber = new Customer(name,phone,email);           //Deklarerar nytt konto. Lagrat värden i konstruktorn!


    firstName = (firstNameIn.getText());
    surName = (surNameIn.getText());
    name = firstName + "" + surName;

    phone = (phoneIn.getText());
    email = (emailIn.getText());

         out.setText("Customer: " +name+ "Phone: " +phone+ "Email: " +email);




}
```